# Set keys and rows cache to a column family using pycassa?

Tags: python, caching, cassandra, thrift, pycassa

I'd like to know if pycassa offers the possibility to set the `keys_cached` and `rows_cached` fields to a specific column family (or even a keyspace)? As shown here using the cassandra cli : http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/configuration/storage_configuration

I found the `alter_column_family` function that takes the `key_cache_size` argument in the doc: http://pycassa.github.io/pycassa/api/pycassa/system_manager.html

But when I check the cache values with pycassaShell after setting the key cache size of a column family ( http://pycassa.github.io/pycassa/assorted/pycassa_shell.html ), it still tells me:

```
Row Cache:                       None%
Key Cache:                       None%
```

And also there's no differences of performance/memory usage after either, and since `alter_column_family` takes `**kwargs` arguments, and apparently doesn't check them, call succeed with any argument name... So I think `key_cache_size` corresponds to nothing... And I didn't find a documentation of what are the possible optional arguments.

Here is cassandra log when it receive the `alter_column_family` call:

```
INFO 17:39:26,338 Update ColumnFamily '53c7deadcc9b10271a2df9f0/B' From org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@3fbd01a[cfId=2dd38542-82ea-381f-be51-44a30af61f24,ksName=53c7deadcc9b10271a2df9f0,cfName=B,cfType=Standard,comparator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.IntegerType,comment=,readRepairChance=0.1,dclocalReadRepairChance=0.0,replicateOnWrite=true,gcGraceSeconds=864000,defaultValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DoubleType,keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.IntegerType,minCompactionThreshold=4,maxCompactionThreshold=32,column_metadata={java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=3 cap=3]=ColumnDefinition{name=6b6579, validator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.IntegerType, type=PARTITION_KEY, componentIndex=null, indexName=null, indexType=null}, java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=5 cap=5]=ColumnDefinition{name=76616c7565, validator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DoubleType, type=COMPACT_VALUE, componentIndex=null, indexName=null, indexType=null}, java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=7 cap=7]=ColumnDefinition{name=636f6c756d6e31, validator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.IntegerType, type=CLUSTERING_KEY, componentIndex=null, indexName=null, indexType=null}},compactionStrategyClass=class org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy,compactionStrategyOptions={},compressionOptions={sstable_compression=org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor},bloomFilterFpChance=<null>,memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0,caching=KEYS_ONLY,defaultTimeToLive=0,speculative_retry=NONE,indexInterval=128,populateIoCacheOnFlush=false,droppedColumns={},triggers={}] To org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@11131f6f[cfId=2dd38542-82ea-381f-be51-44a30af61f24,ksName=53c7deadcc9b10271a2df9f0,cfName=B,cfType=Standard,comparator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.IntegerType,comment=,readRepairChance=0.1,dclocalReadRepairChance=0.0,replicateOnWrite=true,gcGraceSeconds=864000,defaultValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DoubleType,keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.IntegerType,minCompactionThreshold=4,maxCompactionThreshold=32,column_metadata={java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=7 cap=7]=ColumnDefinition{name=636f6c756d6e31, validator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.IntegerType, type=CLUSTERING_KEY, componentIndex=null, indexName=null, indexType=null}, java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=3 cap=3]=ColumnDefinition{name=6b6579, validator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.IntegerType, type=PARTITION_KEY, componentIndex=null, indexName=null, indexType=null}, java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=5 cap=5]=ColumnDefinition{name=76616c7565, validator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DoubleType, type=COMPACT_VALUE, componentIndex=null, indexName=null, indexType=null}},compactionStrategyClass=class org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy,compactionStrategyOptions={},compressionOptions={sstable_compression=org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor},bloomFilterFpChance=<null>,memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0,caching=KEYS_ONLY,defaultTimeToLive=0,speculative_retry=NONE,indexInterval=128,populateIoCacheOnFlush=false,droppedColumns={},triggers={}]
INFO 17:39:26,349 CFS(Keyspace='system', ColumnFamily='schema_columnfamilies') liveRatio is 5.344978165938865 (just-counted was 5.344978165938865).  calculation took 0ms for 25 cells
INFO 17:39:26,349 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-schema_keyspaces@2042821730(138/8832 serialized/live bytes, 3 ops)
WARN 17:39:26,350 setting live ratio to maximum of 64.0 instead of Infinity
INFO 17:39:26,351 CFS(Keyspace='system', ColumnFamily='schema_keyspaces') liveRatio is 64.0 (just-counted was 64.0).  calculation took 1ms for 0 cells
INFO 17:39:26,351 Writing Memtable-schema_keyspaces@2042821730(138/8832 serialized/live bytes, 3 ops)
INFO 17:39:26,368 Completed flushing var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-jb-79-Data.db (177 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1405696976943, position=238330)
INFO 17:39:26,373 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-schema_columnfamilies@200691258(1145/6120 serialized/live bytes, 25 ops)
INFO 17:39:26,373 Writing Memtable-schema_columnfamilies@200691258(1145/6120 serialized/live bytes, 25 ops)
INFO 17:39:26,381 Completed flushing var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-74-Data.db (787 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1405696976943, position=238330)
```

There's an interesting `caching=KEYS_ONLY` argument, which seems in contradiction with pycassaShell output, but nothing about the size of this key cache size, and nothing about the row cache. I get the very same output whether I put `key_cache_size=200000`, `0` or `None`.

So does someone know how to do it through pycassa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Cassandra are you using? pycassa is a bit out of date when it comes to column family attributes (especially within pycassaShell).

`key_cache_size` and `row_cache_size` were replaced by global options (`key_cache_size_in_mb`, `row_cache_size_in_mb`) in cassandra.yaml in Cassandra 1.1.  The `caching` option is the one you should be setting per-column family, and it can be set to `KEYS_ONLY`, `ROWS_ONLY`, `ALL`, or `NONE`.

As a side note, at this point you should generally be using cqlsh instead of cassandra-cli and the [python CQL driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver) instead of pycassa (I maintain both), especially for new projects.

Comment: Thank you! Well actually it didn't changed the performances, but since there's no disk access on my request I guess the row cache is working. My problem is I have a column family with 37 columns and 5735 keys in which I write rarely but I often need to read it entirely, I gave a try to the CQL driver for that very specific problem, and a `SELECT *` is almost 3 times slower than pycassa's `get_range()`, I guess it has something to do with the paging of the results, but in either case there's no options to control it, any idea apart from caching it on my program side?

Comment: Ah just found the `fetch_size` arg of `SimpleStatement`. But I still have a `PagedResult`, and it is clearly blocking every 5000 entries when iterating over it, whatever `fetch_size` I put.

Comment: Ok so I overrode manually my `Session.default_fetch_size` since it apparently doesn't work with the `fetch_size` arg of `SimpleStatement`, and now it works, but it is still about 50% slower than pycassa's get_range() (5.2s vs 3.6s). I wonder why it is so slow for such a small table...

Comment: Just tried to put cassandra data directory in a tmpfs to be sure, no changes, I guess everything was in the file cache from the beginning. Still, I find retrieving this small table very slow.